# Find the worst element making the correlation worse in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I'd like to find the worst record which make the correlation worse in pandas.DataFrame to remove anomaly records.

When I have the following DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[1,2,30]})
```

The correlation becomes better removing third row.

```
print df.corr() #-> correlation is 0.88
print df.ix[0:1].corr() # -> correlation is 1.00
```

In this case, my question is how to find  the third row is an candidate of anomalies which make the correlation worse.

My idea is execute linear regression and calculate the error of each element (row). But, I don't know the simple way to try that idea and also believe there is more simple and straightforward way.

#### Update

Of course, you can remove all of elements and achieve the correlation is 1. But I'd like to find just one (or several) anomaly row(s). Intuitively, I hope to get non-trivial set of records which achieves better correlation.

Comment: For this dataframe, removing ANY row would make the correlation 1.

Comment: Yes. Thank you @Rob, I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

First, you could brute force it to get exact solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations, chain, imap

df = pd.DataFrame(zip(np.random.randn(10), np.random.randn(10)))

# set the maximal number of lines you are willing to remove
reomve_up_to_n = 3

# all combinations of indices to keep
to_keep = imap(list, chain(*map(lambda i: combinations(df.index, df.shape[0] - i), range(1, reomve_up_to_n + 1))))

# find index with highest remaining correlation
highest_correlation_index = max(to_keep, key = lambda ks: df.ix[ks].corr().ix[0,1])

df_remaining = df.ix[highest_correlation_index]
```

This can be costly. You could get a greedy approximation by adding a column with something like row's contribution to correlation.

```
df['CorComp'] = (df.icol(0).mean() - df.icol(0)) * (df.icol(1).mean() - df.icol(1))
df = df.sort(['CorComp'])
```

Now you can remove rows starting from the top, which may raise your correlation.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is about [outliers detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlier). There is many way to perform this detection, but a simple way could be to exclude values with deviation exceeding x % of the standard deviation of the series.

```
# Keep only values with a deviation less than 10% of the standard deviation of the series.
df[np.abs(df.b-df.b.mean())<=(1.1*df.b.std())]

# result
   a  b
0  1  1
1  2  2
```